# Angular directive attributes aren't being passed through

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to shorten my form code by making directives for each element, however my directive is displaying none of what I'm passing to it and the model isn't being bound.

HTML:

```
<formstring dataBinding="project.title" dataTitle="Title" dataPlaceholder="title" />
```

directive:

```
app.directive('formstring', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AEC',
    dataBinding: '=',
    dataTitle: '@dataTitle',
    dataPlaceholder: '@dataPlaceholder',
    dataHelp: '@dataHelp',
    templateUrl: '/app/js/directives/form/string.html',
  };
});
```

string.html:

```
<div class="form-group">  2   <label for="{{dataTitle}}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{dataTitle}}</label    >
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{dataTitle}}" placeholder="{{da    taPlaceholder}}" ng-model="dataBinding">
    <p ng-show="dataHelp" class="help-block">{{dataHelp}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

project is a $scope object that has an attribute 'title'.

What am I missing? Why does this show up at a blank input with none of the attributes filled in and why does the binding not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't understood how directives are configured correctly. I suggest you read the documentation, it may help you understand better.

In the meantime, here is what your HTML, directive code and template should look like (there is also a [working demonstration on Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NNOz1uSPGZvbpKDQHx4K?p=preview)):

HTML:

```
<formstring data-binding="project.title" 
            data-title="Title Demo" 
            data-placeholder="title placeholder"
            data-help="My help text">
</formstring>
```

directive:

```
app.directive('formstring', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        binding: '=',
        title: '@',
        placeholder: '@',
        help: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: '/app/js/directives/form/string.html',
  };
});
```

Template (string.html):

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="{{title}}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
      {{title}}
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{title}}" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-model="binding">
      <p ng-show="help" class="help-block">{{help}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that the leading `data-` from each attribute will be stripped by Angular, see the [Directive Guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#matching-directives) for details.

Comment: Make sure to change the template as well to reference the scope properties without the `data` prefix (and lowercased, of course).

Comment: @JasonMcCarrell I updated my answer to demonstrate what it should be. There is even a working plunkr for you to try it yourself.

Comment: Hmmm you definitely have a working plunkr of my example, but it still doesn't work on my end, so I'll need to try and look harder at the differences. I'll get back to you once I figure out the difference.

Thank you very much so far!

Comment: Apparently I needed to get rid of the prefixes. so title, instead of dataTitle in the string.html template.
Thanks! I'm guessing the reason I was having such difficult was because I was using the data prefix.

Comment: Yes, most likely. In fact, if you are desperate to have the `data` prefix for your isolate scope properties, you would need to specify them in the directive attributes as `data-data-*`. Ugh. Thankfully, though, "data" is such a generic term, surely in most cases you can come up with a better name?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change how you're creating isolate scope:

```
app.directive('formstring', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AEC',
    scope: {
       dataBinding: '=',
       dataTitle: '@dataTitle',
       dataPlaceholder: '@dataPlaceholder',
       dataHelp: '@dataHelp'
    },
    templateUrl: '/app/js/directives/form/string.html',
  };
});
```

Read [the doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for details about what an isolate/isolated scope means because it has an effect on the overall scope.

edit:
I didn't notice this additional issue before.  Your camel case scope properties become snake cased when you use your directive (see Mobin's answer):

```
<formstring data-binding="project.title" data-title="Title" data-placeholder="title" />
```

In your template, however, the properties are still camel cased as you have:

```
<div class="form-group">  2   <label for="{{dataTitle}}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{dataTitle}}</label    >
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{dataTitle}}" placeholder="{{da    taPlaceholder}}" ng-model="dataBinding">
    <p ng-show="dataHelp" class="help-block">{{dataHelp}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is because the bindings in your template are JSON properties, whereas the attributes when you use your directive's properties are XML properties.

There are minor tweaks I'd apply to your template, for instance `id="{{dataTitle}}"` can easily break HTML standards that require the id attribute is unique... you probably want to use `name="{{dataTitle}}"` instead. `name` could still cause issues, but it wont' break `document.getElementById` for example.

Also, I'd use `ng-bind` whenever possible:

```
<p ng-show="dataHelp" class="help-block" ng-bind="dataHelp"></p>
```

Comment: Hmmm, you are correct that I should be using an isolated scope, but still nothing shows up, even with your suggested change.

Comment: oh. I didn't notice when I answered previously, the xml doesn't allow camel case, so `dataBinding` in your scope has to be declared as `data-binding=""` in your view. I'll update the answer for clarity.

Comment: I was just doing it super wrong, because I was afraid data- would be reserved and mess things up... and it was =P.
I needed to remove the data- prefix, then everything worked as suggested by Greg above. Your answer was also good, because it reminded me to use an isolated scope. Thanks!

Comment: ah, yeah, I guess you'd have to put `data-data-binding` if your scope's property is `dataBinding`. I should have recognized that from the start. :D

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
<formstring data-binding="project.title" data-title="Title" data-placeholder="title" />
```

.